# To find and replace multiple lines in the same file in shell using grep and sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed, scripting, grep

`grep -A 4 -B 3 "ABCD" file.txt | sed -i.bak 's/^/#/g'`

I am using above code to insert first line of searched pattern with #.
I need to replace multiple lines on the basis of one searched pattern.
These contents have to replaced(substituted) in the same file or the new file should contain original content as well.

Below is the example of expected output from the input file.

Suppose content of file.txt is -

```
PQRS
1
2
3
4
ABCD
1
2
3
4
WXYZ
1
2
3
4
ABCD
1
2
3
4
```

Expected output is -

```
PQRS
1
#2
#3
#4
#ABCD
#1
#2
#3
#4
WXYZ
1
#2
#3
#4
#ABCD
#1
#2
#3
#4
```

Any ideas here.
Is there a subtle way to do this instead of looping and moving file pointer using perl or any other scripting.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to prepend with a `#` the 3 lines before the pattern, the next 4 lines after the pattern and the pattern line itself?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/\n/&/7;Ta;/(.*\n){3}ABCD(.*\n){4}/s/^[^#]/#&/mg;P;D' file
```

Gather up 7 lines and if the fourth line begins `ABCD` insert `#` before each of the 7 lines (unless it already has been commented).

An alternative using grep:

```
grep -n -A4 -B3 'ABCD' file | 
sed -nE 's/^([0-9]+).*/\1s@^[^#]@#\&@/p' | sed -f - file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an inline sed approach:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pattern=${1:-ABCD}
input=${2:-file.txt}

sed "
/^[[:upper:]]*$/ {
    /$pattern/ {  # if target pattern, append the next line and comment both
        N
        s/^/#/
        s/\n/\n#/
    }
}

/^[[:digit:]]*$/ {  # if digit(s), comment out if it's not a 1
    /^1$/! {
        s/^/#/
    }
}
" $input
```